# Calling a function with a vector of objects through another function

Tags: c++

I am having issues (not necessarily with errors but the console turning blank) when I try to call another function in a while loop iterating over a vector of objects.

Basically `fightEnemy` won't show up when I run it through the while loop, but it will when I don't run it through the while loop in the `enemyComboCheck` function.

My Code:

```
int fightEnemy(Player &player, Enemy &enemy) {
    //just for example
    cout << player.name << endl;
    cout << enemy.name << endl;
    return 0;
}

int enemyComboCheck(int id1, int id2, vector<Player> &allPlayers, vector<Enemy> &allEnemies){
    int iteratorForPlayer = 0;
    int iteratorForEnemy = 0;
    id1 = id1 - 1;
    id2 = id2 - 1;

    while(true){
        if(id1 == allPlayers[iteratorForPlayer].id && id2 == allEnemies[iteratorForEnemy].eid) fightEnemy(allPlayers[iteratorForPlayer], allEnemies[iteratorForEnemy]); break;
        if(iteratorForEnemy <= 18) iteratorForEnemy++;
        if(iteratorForPlayer <= 5) iteratorForPlayer++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    vector<Player> allPlayers; //pretend this has 5 players
    vector<Enemy> allEnemies; //pretend this has 18 enemies
    enemyComboCheck(uid1, uid2, allPlayers, allEnemies); //this won't print out fightEnemy while in the while loop
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it changed the question and invalidated the current answer (which is also mine). If you have another question that is a good fit for the site, you can ask it as another question. However, it sounds like you need to step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use a debugger :/

Comment: Your loop will continue to spin forever if the `if` statement is never met. In your loop, you can print the values of `id1, id2, allPlayers[iteratorForPlayer].id, allEnemies[iteratorForEnemy].id` and have the loop wait for input (`cin.get()`) each iteration so you can see what the values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `break` hidden after the `if` statement. It will always exit the loop during the first iteration because it isn't included in the `if` block.

Comment: Thanks for that point out, although now when id1 or id2 is over 1 it freezes up, I edited my question a bit.

Comment: @PeteMcGreetetheIIII there still is a break